# How to change GraphQL Schema at runtime in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql

There is Spring Boot backend with GraphQL implemented already and I have a dynamic database that users can use to create new tables and columns. According to this information, I need to implement a dynamic schema that can be changed in runtime to my backend. I found that GraphQL Schema is immutable once it is built, so I cannot perform any change. But in [documentation](https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/schema) it says we can achieve this with a schema transformer. So, I tried the documentation method and used **SchemaTranformer** with
**GraphQLTypeVisitorStub**.

```java
@PostConstruct
public void init() throws SQLException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
    Path graphQLSchemaFilePath = Paths.get(
            Objects.requireNonNull(this.getClass().getResource(GRAPHQL_SCHEMA_FILE)).toURI());
    GraphQLSchema localSchema = buildSchema(graphQLSchemaFilePath);
    graphQLSchema = localSchema;
    this.graphQL = GraphQL.newGraphQL(graphQLSchema).build();

    // below code is to test if in runtime does it add the new types
    // normally these methods are not going to be used 
    // these methods will get triggered from other services
    databaseMetaData = getDBMetaData();
    schemaTranformation();
}
```

Firstly, I have a *schema.graphql* file with base queries and types, that backend needs for running. It imports and runs without any errors. Then, it gets meta data for only demo purposes to try adding new type from database.

```java
public List<GraphQLObjectType> createSchema(String tableName) throws SQLException {
    List<GraphQLObjectType> objectTypes = new ArrayList<>();

    resultSet = databaseMetaData.getColumns(null, null, (String) tableName, null);
    GraphQLObjectType.Builder builder = GraphQLObjectType.newObject();

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        builder
                .name(tableName.toLowerCase())
                .field(GraphQLFieldDefinition.newFieldDefinition()
                        .name(resultSet.getString("COLUMN_NAME"))
                        .type(GraphQLNonNull.nonNull(returnType(resultSet.getString("TYPE_NAME")))))
                .build();
    }

    objectTypes.add(builder.build());
    return objectTypes;
}
```

With the above method, I tried to return new object types as a list. After that, I created the *schemaTransformation* method which you'll see below, gets new types with fields from *createSchema* method and tries to transform the schema.

```java
public void schemaTransformation() throws SQLException {
    resultSet = databaseMetaData.getTables(null, null, null, new String[]{"TABLE"});
    tables = new ArrayList<>();

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        tables.add(resultSet.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
    }

    List<List<GraphQLObjectType>> createdSchemas = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String table : tables) {
        createdSchemas.add(createSchema(table));
    }
    for (List<GraphQLObjectType> graphQLObjectTypeList : createdSchemas) {
        for (GraphQLObjectType graphQLObjectType : graphQLObjectTypeList) {
            GraphQLTypeVisitorStub visitorSub = getVisitorSub(graphQLObjectType);
            this.graphQLSchema = SchemaTransformer.transformSchema(this.graphQLSchema, visitorSub);
        }
    }
}
```

But at *SchemaTransformer.transformSchema()*, it gives null pointer exception. Also, I did not add `this.graphQL = GraphQL.newGraphQL(this.graphQLSchema).build();` this code because I do not know if it is needed.

```java
private GraphQLTypeVisitorStub getVisitorSub(GraphQLObjectType graphQLObjectType) {
    return new GraphQLTypeVisitorStub() {
        @Override
        public TraversalControl visitGraphQLObjectType(GraphQLObjectType objectType,
                                                        TraverserContext<GraphQLSchemaElement> context) {
            GraphQLCodeRegistry.Builder codeRegistryBuilder = context.getVarFromParents(
                    GraphQLCodeRegistry.Builder.class);
            List<GraphQLFieldDefinition> graphQLFieldDefinitions = new ArrayList<>(graphQLObjectType.getFields());
            DataFetcher newDataFetcher = dataFetchingEnvironment -> {
                return userService.healthCheck();
            };

            FieldCoordinates fieldCoordinates = null;
            for (GraphQLFieldDefinition fieldDefinition : graphQLFieldDefinitions) {
                fieldCoordinates = FieldCoordinates.coordinates(
                        objectType.getName(), fieldDefinition.getName());
                codeRegistryBuilder.dataFetcher(fieldCoordinates, newDataFetcher);
            }
            
            return insertAfter(context, graphQLObjectType);
        }
    };
}
```

This method returns the visitor that I need to use in *transformSchema* method.

So, am I doing the wrong way of changing schema in runtime or is the dependency has a bug? Maybe it is impossible to change graphql schema in runtime. I do not know

Comment: I think running time changes at the endpoint is not good. Source of unexpected errors. It makes some problems in future. What if multiple clients use the same dynamic endpoint and one removes one "endpoint" that another would like to use? How would sync them?

Comment: If you are asking about the client side to sync them, I solve that problem by getting schema types from /graphql. You are right about the changes at the endpoint in runtime but I need to register users' new tables as types and columns as fields in order to access these data via using graphql. Main idea is making graphql schema a dynamic one for accessing the new data.